# What exacty does ゆえ mean, and how does it fit this JLPT question?

Tags: word-choice, jlpt

I have this question in my JLPT textbook:

> 男女{だんじょ}平等{びょうどう}といっても、女性{じょせい}＿＿＿の差別{さべつ}はまだ残{のこ}っている。
>
> **A** ゆえ　**B** たる　**C** なり　**D** こそ

The book says the answer is A, which is weird to me because I thought `ゆえ` was kind of like "ergo", or "as a result from". If you say `女性{じょせい}ゆえ`, it seems to me like one is saying that somehow the `差別{さべつ}` is *because* of women.

So I must have `ゆえ` wrong. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: This is a good one, thanks for asking it.

Comment: I came here to ask this same question about this same practice sentence!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`故{ゆえ}` appears to mean many different things depending on the way it's used, but the main definition seems to be "reason".

- `ゆえの`: "by reason of (being)", "due to (being)" or "because of (being)". 
  Whether to add or omit "being" can only be determined by context:

  > 女性ゆえの差別
  >   "discrimination by reason of being a woman."
  >   有名人ゆえの苦労
  >   "hardships by reason of being a famous person."
  >   熟練ゆえの効率の良さ
  >   "efficiency by reason of skill."
- `X（が）ゆえに`: "for the reason of X" or "because of X":

  > 信念を貫くがゆえに拷問を受ける
  > "be tortured for the reason of one's faith"
- `（それ）ゆえに` at the start of a sentence etc: "for that reason", "therefore" or "thus":

  > 故に商品の質は、信頼そのものになる
  >   "for that reason, product quality is consumer confidence."

According to [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%82%86%E3%81%88&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0), it can also mean "of splendid history" when written as `故ある人` and `故ある家` etc, "taste/atmosphere", "relation/affinity" and "break-down/accident".

Answer (score 8):

In this sentence, 女性ゆえの差別 does not mean “discrimination (against someone) because of a woman,” but it means “discrimination (against someone) because of (that person) being a woman.”  That is, it means the fact that some people discriminate against a person because the person is a woman.

Answer (score 3):

I can find this in [a dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/77275/m0u/%E3%82%86%E3%81%88/) :

> 3 〔…のために〕
>
> それゆえに
>
> for that **reason**
>
> 悪天候ゆえに旅行は延期された
>
> 「**Because of [On account of]** the bad weather, the trip was postponed.
>
> 何ゆえにうそをついたのか
>
> Why did you lie?

which explicitly used **because of** in the translation.

And I think try to find one word (or phrase) as an equivalent of a word (or phrase) in another language is just impossible. So maybe sometimes ゆえ means "as a result of", but that does not mean it is equivalent to it.

EDIT:

In "女性ゆえの差別", the "ゆえ" here is to show the reason why a person got discriminated (because of that she is a woman). The literal meaning has been given in Ito's answer. However, in English there not such a way to express discrimination, so the translation becomes "discrimination against women".