# What are the detailed grammatical rules for using ゆえ?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I remember first hearing it in the Japanese catchphrase for Kino's Journey, as "世界は美しくなんかない。そしてそれゆえに美しい". I was curious to look up that part of the sentence in my resources, and turned up a translation for "I think, therefore I am(我思う, ゆえに我あり)", along with a few bits I gleaned from its grammatical uses. I think I have a good idea on how to use it, but I want to be sure before I go forward with it

Comment: これとか・・・https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3959/9831